# Is there a way to affect the bone hierarchy generated by rigify?

Tags: rigging, add-on, rigify

The standard human metarig of rigify 0.5 (blender 2.79) is great. It has its root node at the hips and from there the node hirarchy is built following the spine up to the chest with its shoulders and neck, etc, and also down the thighs to the feet and toes.

But the generated resulting rig does not follow this clear hirarchy. It is for the lack of a better word... scrambled. Feet become siblings of hands, etc.

I know it is a little more complex and in reality the resulting rig is probably three separate rigs in one. The original bones, mixed with generated deform bones, mixed with group bones, etc.

But the hirarchy is gone and replaced by what seems unordered chaoes held together by transformation constraints.

So my question would be: is there a way to modify the way the bone hirarchy is generated making it so, that the ORG bones maintain proper hirarchy and the rest dangles of of them or build their own hirarchy not bothering the ORG bone hirarchy?

Comment: The rigify rig is simply a long python script which you can easily edit. Even though I don't have it open right now, I am pretty sure, the original bone hierarchy is still there with the deforming bones (hidden).

Comment: The ORG bone hierarchy was preserved in the previous version of rigify (you can enable it using legacy mode). But in the new version, the ORG bone hierarch is also scrambled. Do not get me wrong. The bones are still there in their layer, but not in the original hierarchy.